# Symfony 3 : Build forms for entities based on Traits

Tags: forms, symfony, embed, traits

I'm having a hard time building forms for my entities that are themselves built with traits.

For example my "Article" entity only contains the link to the category and 2 pics, the rest of its properties is in the SeoTrait (title, meta_title, meta_desc, content, etc...), ValidTrait (isValid true/false)... which I want to use for other entities.

It all works fine for doctrine, that generates my schema with all the fields from the Traits in each entity that use them. The problem is for the forms :

I've created the SeoTraitType for the "SEO" properties :

```
class SeoTraitType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Nom'
            ))
            ->add('metaTitle', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Meta Title'
            ))
            ->add('metaDescription', TextareaType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Meta Description'
            ))
            ->add('metaKeywords', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Keywords'
            ))
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Content'
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

And then I'm using it in my ArticleType :

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('seo', SeoTraitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Seo',
                'mapped' => false
            ))
            ->add('isValid',    ValidTraitType::class,      array(
                'label' => 'Valid',
                'mapped' => false
            ))
            ->add('save',       SubmitType::class,          array(
                'label' => 'form_save',
                'translation_domain' => 'back_default'
            ));
        ;
    }
}
```

The two problems I have here is that I must set mapped => false for the 2 TraitTypes when I want to embed them in my main entity's form
And then in my form I get article[seo][name] for the SeoTrait's fields, so I can't really use the $form->handleRequest() methods and all... to handle the submission of my form

I was wondering if there is a special way to do this within the provided methods of the form component, or if I just have to handle the request myself and parse the trait arrays myself to build my entity before saving it ? I couldn't really find anything on the internet :(

Comment: Jean, have you looked at the Symfony article [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)? I've been meaning to write an article on this since the docs aren't very good. You might be able to do what you need to achieve by embedding forms. It will take some time to get familiar with how everything is done, so i would suggests going through the article.

Comment: **Don't do this**. Symfony's form component has a **builtin** mechanism for reusing forms. You can re-use/nest subforms providing a set of fields easily by setting the `inherit_data` option to `true` inside the parent form. No need for a trait! There are several benefits from working with an embedded type and `inherit_data` -
 as opposed to using a trait - i.e. the embedded form's event-listeners will continue to work. Good Testability gets lost with when using a trait. Try to get familiar with embeddable subform-types and Doctrine Embeddables - there is a cleaner way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I read the article above, but it only talks about embedding forms for related entities, wether it's only one object or a collection of objects, which I will use later on, but I didn't see anything about being able to import another form without it having a field name, and then all the fields inherited being in that field name... I'll give it a fresh look on monday, thanks guys !

Comment: nifr your rock, https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/inherit_data_option.html That's exactly what I needed, it also does the job perfectly !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve your problem is to transform your class `SeoTraitType` into a `Trait`.

like:

```
trait SeoTraitType
{
    public function buildSEOForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Nom'
            ))
            ->add('metaTitle', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Meta Title'
            ))
            ->add('metaDescription', TextareaType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Meta Description'
            ))
            ->add('metaKeywords', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Keywords'
            ))
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Content'
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    use SeoTraitType;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->buildSEOForm($builder, $options);

        $builder
            ->add('isValid',    ValidTraitType::class,      array(
                'label' => 'Valid',
                'mapped' => false
            ))
            ->add('save',       SubmitType::class,          array(
                'label' => 'form_save',
                'translation_domain' => 'back_default'
            ));
        ;
    }
}
```

You can also do this with static method. Not a big fan of Trait.

Comment: OMG you are a god !! Thank you so much ;) It does exactly what I wanted !

Comment: @JeanBaptisteRacoupeau Thanks ;-) so you can accept the question if it work for you

Answer (score 2):

Ok so the Trait solution works fine, but I chose to go for this method here :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/inherit_data_option.html

Thanks so much guys, I was pretty sure that the solution would be somewhere in the documentation but couldn't find it !